# Multiple load balancers Tomcat is it Viable?

Tags: haproxy, mod-cluster

Question: 
Could HAProxy and Mod_Cluster and Tomcat be used together ?

Either Mod_Cluster+Tomcat or HAProxy+Tomcat but not HAProxy+Mod_Cluster+Tomcat unless we are setting up multiple load balancer correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain mod_cluster Apache HTTP Server balancer behind HAProxy, both in TCP and HTTP mode, in front of Tomcat.  You could also use mod_cluster Apache HTTP Server balancer and HAProxy side-by-side, having them both sending requests to your Tomcats. The latter makes much less sense though.

If you tell me what would you like to achieve in which environment, I could help you architect the right solution. For instance: Azure, multiple datacentres, VMs, clients are plain HTTP embedded devices or Docker containers on Tutum/Docker Cloud, clients use HTTPS and certificate for authentication.   You can / cannot use AJP internally between mod_cluster and Tomcat etc. Help me help you :-) -K-

Comment: Thanks Michal for confirming!! If you don't mind me asking what would be the benefit of chaining them?

Comment: I don't know any for HTTP mode, but definitely, you might use, e.g. Docker Cloud's own provided HA proxy in TCP mode and put your mod_cluster setup behind it. You would design your worker containers and balancer containers in stacks and set their geolocations and let DockerCloud HAProxy in TCP mode balance traffic to Apache HTTP Servers.   It vastly depends on your environment.